# How can I copy the code inside the <code> tag to the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I tried this code but it doesn't work. How can I copy the code inside the `<code>` tag to the clipboard?

```
 <pre id="myCode">
   <code>
      console.log("hello world!")
   </code>
 </pre>
```

JavaScript

```
function copyScript(){
 document.getElementById('myCode').select();
 document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) function can only be used on input elements such as `<textarea>` or `<input>`.

If you want to use it with your `<code>` tag, one way to accomplish it would be to copy the contents of the tag into a new `<textarea>` object and copy from that:

```
function copyScript() {
    // get the text to copy
    var codeText = document.getElementById('myCode').textContent;
    
    // create a textarea with the text we want to copy and add it to the page
    var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textArea.textContent = codeText;
    document.body.append(textArea);
    
    // focus on the new textarea and copy the contents!
    textArea.focus();
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

Comment: @FurkanKarakuzu I don't think you need to rely on a framework for this, it's built-in to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do this for modern browsers

```
function copyToClipboard {
    let codeText = document.getElementById('myCode').textContent;
    // copying
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(codeText)
}
```